# Spacebar is causing unwanted text while running a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am using a script I found on a tutorial. The purpose of the script is to have something similar to facebook and twitter where you can type a name after entering the @ symbol.  A  dropdown then pops up and lists names.

The script is working great.  The problem is if a user needs to start typing in more than just a first name (to narrow down the results further), they enter a space before typing in the last name naturally. You cant see the problem at this point yet, and the names continue to narrow down and the dropdown/popup remains correctly.  Once you click the link of the person you are looking for, it inserts that player as a link in my textarea properly, but it also includes just the first few letters of the last name on the outside of the link as well.

Works fine if typed like so and then click the name that pops up:  @fname

Not working when typed like this: @fname lna

The results will show "fname lname" in the pop up like its supposed to but what is inserted into my textarea when clicked is like so..

```
lna<ahref>afname lname</a>
```

(the ahref is not actually showing just put there for example.

Here is a link to a working demo of the script I am using.

http://demos.9lessons.info/tagfriends.html

If you go there and type in @sri in the search box, then continue typing in the first name that pops up and press the spacebar, then start typing the first few letters of the last name.  Then click on the name.  You will see what I mean.

Here is the code where I believe the error can be fixed or edit.  I have searched and searched for a solutions but couldn't find anything. I thought about disabling the space bar but I need that to remain working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

$("#contentbox").live("keyup",function() 
{
var content=$(this).text();
var go= content.match(start);
var name= content.match(word);
var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

if(go.length>0)
{
$("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
$("#display").slideUp('show');
$("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
if(name.length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "boxsearch.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

}
}
return false();
});


$(".addname").live("click",function() 
{
var username=$(this).attr('title');
var old=$("#contentbox").html();
var content=old.replace(word,""); 
$("#contentbox").html(content);
var E="<a href=''>"+username+"</a>";
$("#contentbox").append(E);
$("#display").hide();
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#contentbox").focus();
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the `var word` regex to match spaces as well, by adding \s: `/@([\w\s]+)/ig`

That should allow your `var content=old.replace(word,"");` call to match "fname lname" completely.

With that change you may also need to replace spaces with "%20" in `dataString` in your call to $.ajax. I can't remember whether jquery does that for you automatically:

`data: dataString.replace(/\ +/g, '%20'),`

Comment: This works perfect thank you!!!!  I didn't have to replace spaces with "%20" in call to ajax.